# Como inserir Html no XML?

Tags: html, xml

Existe algum jeito de inserir html no xml?
Eu queria inserir algumas propriedades do html no meu codigo, posso fazer isso? De que forma?
Se for possivel me ajudem, sou novo nessa area então nao me esculachem.

Comment: Isso não faz sentido. XML é uma linguagem de marcação livre de contexto, ou seja, o contexto define como o XML deve ser interpretado. Pode usar HTML no XML? No XML do que? Faz sentido HTML no contexto do XML que você está utilizando?

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo? É a mesma coisa que querer colocar csv dentro de json ou usar NoSQL dentro de SQL, não faz sentido. Exemplifique seu caso

Answer (score 3):

Sim, é possível, é só utilizar CDATA: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA

Exemplo:

```
<xml>
    <title>Your HTML title</title>
    <htmlData><![CDATA[<html>
        <head>
            <script/>
        </head>
        <body>
        Your HTML's body
        </body>
        </html>
     ]]>
    </htmlData>
</xml>
```

Créditos do exemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412395/is-it-possible-to-insert-html-content-in-xml-document

Boa sorte